# Querying with mongoose - Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

**Base field used in all schemas.**

```
var base_param = {
     creation_date: {
         type: Date,
         default: Date.now
     },
     modification_date: {
         type: Date,
         default: Date.now
     },
     visibility: {
         type: Boolean,
         default: true
     }
 };

 module.exports = base_param;
```

**Example of schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var constant = require('../util/constant');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var base_param = require('./base/base-parameter');

var time = {
    timefrom: Date,
    timeto: Date,
    holidaytype: Number,
    status: {
        type: Number,
        enum: [constant().status.pending, constant().status.accepted, constant().status.rejected, constant().status.todelete],
        default: constant().status.pending
    }
}

var holidaySchema = new Schema({
    employee: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Employee'
    },
    workday: Date,
    times: [time],
    employee_notified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    hr_notified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    base_param: base_param
});


module.exports = holidaySchema;
```

The `visibility` field when false denotes that a document has been deleted(soft delete).

What i would like to do is use the following `middleware` to filter my queries with `base_param.visibility = true` in my RESTful web services (for example inject in the query param of the holidays service).

```
var express = require('express');
    var routes = function () {
        var router = express.Router();
        router.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
            var query = req.query;
            query.base_param = new Object();
            query.base_param.visibility = true;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(query));
            next();
        });
        return router;
    };
    module.exports = routes;
```

**The holiday controller service**

```
 var controller = function (Holiday) {
        var get = function (req, res) {
            var query = req.query;
            console.log('inside holidayController\'s get, query: ' + JSON.stringify(query))
            console.log('visibility: ' + query.base_param.visibility);
            var perPage = req.query.perPage;
            var page = req.query.page;
            var date = req.query.date;
            var year = req.query.year;
            var month = req.query.month;
            if (page > 0) {
                page = page - 1;
            }
            delete req.query.perPage;
            delete req.query.page;
            delete req.query.date;
            delete req.query.year;
            delete req.query.month;

           /* query.times = {
                status: 1
            };*/

            if (date) {
                var holidayDate = new Date(date);
                holidayDate = new Date(holidayDate.getFullYear(), holidayDate.getMonth(), holidayDate.getDate());
                holidayDate.setDate(1);
                var nextMonthDate = new Date(holidayDate.getFullYear(), holidayDate.getMonth(), holidayDate.getDate());
                nextMonthDate.setMonth(nextMonthDate.getMonth() + 1);
                query.workday = {
                    "$gte": holidayDate,
                    "$lt": nextMonthDate
                };
            } else if (year && month) {
                dateRange = utility().getDateRangeByMonth(month, year);
                utility().filterQueryByWorkDay(query, dateRange);
            }
            Holiday.find(query, function (err, models) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.status(500).send(err);
                    } else {
                        utility().sortInnerArray(models, 'times', 'timefrom');
                        res.json(models);
                    }
                })
                .sort({
                    workday: 1
                })
                .limit(perPage)
                .skip(perPage * page);
        };
```

The service returns an empty array instead of the data. If I use  `Holiday.find('base_param.visibility : true', function (err, models) {`, i get the desired list. I don't know where I am wrong as I do get access the visibility field in the previous code. Please help.

Comment: What is the value of "query" when you put it into the find?  Are you sure it is the same as your hardcoded query?

Comment: Yes Sir. The value of query is `{"base_param": {"visibility": true}}`

Comment: Are you sure that that should work?  It seems to me that you are passing in an object for which base_param.visibility === true, but not the exact value, "baseparam.visibility: true".